# I can't seem to do a POST to MySQL...with the ORMs I created

Tags: mysql, orm

```
create: function(tableInput, colname1, colname2, colname3, colname4, colname5, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, callback) {
    var queryString = "INSERT INTO books ?? (?? ?? ?? ?? ??) VALUES (? ? ? ? ?)";
    console.log(queryString);
    connection.query(queryString, [tableInput, colname1, colname2, colname3, colname4, colname5, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        callback(result);
    });
},
```

Currently, stuck with this error message. The values is posting to the router and showing up in console.log... however there must be something wrong either with the parameter or querystring because it's not taking in any input.

```
-----------------------------
posting to crud
sakl k k lkl klk
INSERT INTO books ?? (?? ?? ?? ?? ??) VALUES (? ? ? ? ?)
C:\Users\nguye\documents\projects\mlbt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`books` (`title` `author` `edition` `ISBN` `publisher`) VALUES ('sakl' 'k' 'k' '' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that stick out:

- The double question marks. Shouldn't they be also single ones?
- You already have a table in your query string and then add another one via parameters (`books`). Remove the hardcoded one from the query string.